# Saw Horses with legs 26" in height

Tags: trigonometry

I am building sawhorses with each end cut at a $14^{\circ}$ angle, where one end attaches to the underside of the sawhorse and the other $14^{\circ}$ angle hits the flat floor.

My question: if I need my leg height to be $26 \text{ inches}$, with $14^{\circ}$ angles cut at each end, what needs to be the length of each leg? Thank you for all your help.

Phil

Comment: So the wood angles up from the floor at 14 degrees? That seems too small.

Comment: this is a reference: http://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/display/FH12OCT_GRTSAH_12.JPG

Comment: my question: if I want the height from floor to underside of the saw-horse to be 26" tall, whats the length of the board?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The length $L$ of the leg board after the cuts have been made will be $$L=\frac{26}{cos(14^{\circ})}$$
or

$$L \approx 26.8$$

Answer (score -1):

The answer above is correct and is for a straight leg with a splay in one direction. However if you want the leg splayed in two directions at 14 degrees  you would have two 14 degree triangles to consider. Therefore you would have to double the difference between 26.8 and 26 and the leg would now be 27.6 inches long.